# form_for - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If I type a user's username and password, everything works fine, BUT if I type nothing or just the username the following error appears:

`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` in
`<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => user_sign_in_path(@user), :html => {:class => 'navbar-form', :role => 'login'} do |user_form_builder|%>`

`app/views/user/sign_in.html.erb:10:in '_app_views_user_sign_in_html_erb__420697496_32907636'
app/controllers/user_controller.rb:23:in 'login'`

I think you'll need the controller, route and view:

**View:**

```
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :url => user_sign_in_path(@user), :html => {:class => 'navbar-form', :role => 'login'} do |user_form_builder|%>
      <div class="form-group text-xs">
        <%= user_form_builder.text_field :username, :class => 'form-control input-xs', :placeholder => 'eMail or Username'%><br>
        <%= user_form_builder.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control input-xs', :placeholder => 'Passwort'%><br>
        <div class="checkbox pull-left">
          <label class="">
            <input type="checkbox"> Angemeldet bleiben
          </label>
        </div>
        <%= user_form_builder.submit 'Anmelden', :class => 'btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right'%><br><br>
        oder <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Registrieren</button>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def sign_in
    @user = User.new
  end

  def login
    username_or_email = params[:user][:username]
    password = params[:user][:password]

    if username_or_email.rindex('@')
      email = username_or_email
      user = User.authenticate_by_email(email, password)
    else
      username = username_or_email
      user = User.authenticate_by_username(username, password)
    end

    if user
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Unknown user. Please check your username and password.'
      render :action => "sign_in"
    end
  end

  def change_pw
  end

  def forgot_pw
  end

  def new
  end

  def sent_pw
  end

  def signed_out
  end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Calendar::Application.routes.draw do
  root "welcome#index"

  get "user/change_pw" => "user#change_pw"
  get "user/forgot_pw" => "user#forgot_pw"
  get "user/new" => "user#new"
  get "user/sent_pw" => "user#sent_pw"
  get "user/sign_in" => "user#sign_in"
  get "user/signed_out" => "user#signed_out"
  get "welcome/index"

  post "user/sign_in" => "user#login"
end
```

I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On failure to authenticate, you are rendering `sign_in` action.  With `render`, as opposed to `redirect_to`, the action does not execute; it only renders the action's view. 
So, the expected `@user` instance variable is not defined in the `login` action which is the reason for this error.

Try updating `login` action as follows:

```
  def login
    ...

    if user
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Unknown user. Please check your username and password.'

      # Assign user to instance variable for the `sign_in` view!
      @user = user 

      render :action => "sign_in"
    end
  end
```

And instead of defining an extra variable, you could choose to replace all local `user` variables with instance variables as `@user` in your `login` action.

**Update:** The quickest workaround to this problem would be to create a new user with the supplied parameters as follows:

```
def login
    ...

    if user
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Unknown user. Please check your username and password.'

      # Create new user instance variable for the `sign_in` view!
      @user = User.new(params[:user]) 

      render :action => "sign_in"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Still didn't work. I get the same error as before. I do not understand this: "And instead of defining an extra variable, you could choose to replace all local user variables with instance variables as @user in your login action."

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, what I was trying to say was instead of adding the line `@user = user` in the `else` block, you could do `@user = User.authenticate_by_username(username, password)`.  Similarly replace other occurrences of `user` with `@user`.

Comment: That would mean that `User.authenticate_by_username` method is returning `nil` or `empty`.  So you should either build an user object with the given parameters in either the authenticate method or in the controller.  Updating answer...

Comment: `User.authenticate_by_username` returns nil, that's right. `@user = User.new(params[:user])` works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update `login` method as below:

```
  def login
    username_or_email = params[:user][:username]
    password = params[:user][:password]

    if username_or_email.rindex('@')
      email = username_or_email
      user = User.authenticate_by_email(email, password)
    else
      username = username_or_email
      user = User.authenticate_by_username(username, password)
    end

    if user
      flash[:notice] = 'Welcome'
      redirect_to :root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Unknown user. Please check your username and password.'
       @user = User.new   ## Set @user instance variable
      render :action => "sign_in"
    end
  end
```

You are getting error because `@user` instance variable is not set in case of authentication failure.

Also, you might want to replace `user` with `@user` as suggested by **Vee**.
Otherwise, if you are accessing `@user` in case of successful authentication (on root page),   then again you'll get error.

Comment: I replaced every `user` with `@user`, but I don't understand why I should do.

Comment: @Ismoh I have it in my answer "Why you should do it". If on root page you are going to access the user record, like name of the user or something then how would you do that unless you have an instance variable `@user` for your rescue. Local variable `user` will not be accessible in your view.